# Use results from two queries with common key to create a dataframe without having to use merge

Tags: python, pandas

data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],index=['abcd','efgh','abcd','abc123','efgh']).reset_index()

s = pd.Series(data=[True,True,False],index=['abcd','efgh','abc123'], name='availability').reset_index()
```

(feel free to remove the reset_index bits above, they are simply there to easily provide a different approach to the problem. however, the resulting datasets from the queries i'm running resemble the above most accurately)

I have two separate queries that return data similar to the above. One query queries one field from a DB that has one column of information that does not exist in the other. The 'index' column is the common key across both tables.

My result set needs to have the 2nd query's result series injected into the first query's resulting dataframe at a specific column index.

I know that I can simply run:

```
df = df.merge(s, how='left', on='index')
```

Then to enforce column order:

```
df = df[['index', 'A', 'B', 'availability', 'C', 'D']
```

I saw that you can do df.inject, but that requires that the series be the same length as the df.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having to run merge and then enforce column order. With my actual dataset, the number of columns is significantly longer. I'd imagine the best solution likely relies on list manipulation, but I'd much rather do something clever with how the dataframe is created in the first place.

```
df.set_index(['index','id']).index.map(s['availability'])
```

is returning:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

S is a dataframe with a multi-index and one column which is a boolean.

df is a dataframe with columns in it which make up S's multi-index

Comment: Just wondering - why don't you want to do it on the SQL DB side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [260]: df.insert(3, 'availability', 
                    df['index'].map(s.set_index('index')['availability']))

In [261]: df
Out[261]:
    index         A         B  availability         C         D
0    abcd  1.867270  0.517894          True  0.584115 -0.162361
1    efgh -0.036696  1.155110          True -1.112075  2.005678
2    abcd  0.693795 -0.843335          True -1.003202  1.001791
3  abc123 -1.466148 -0.848055         False -0.373293  0.360091
4    efgh -0.436618 -0.625454          True -0.285795 -0.220717
```

Comment: @YaleNewman, yeah, we can use it instead of `merge`, when merging a single column...

Comment: is it possible to join a table on aurora with a table on redshift? i've seen joins that are like db.table.column = db1.table1.column, but have always just done all the joins in pandas

Comment: I'm getting an error with my actual data TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: I included the snippet of code that isn't working for me. I realized that I needed to add another column to the index so that may be throwing everything off.

Comment: @YaleNewman, sorry i don't know much about "aurora" and "redshift". In regards to your error message - you used a different code. Does your `s` DF already have a proper index?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830230/unable-to-use-map-function-with-multi-index?noredirect=1#comment78619069_45830230