# unable to use map function with multi-index to inject series into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The Data:

```
data = {"uid":{"0":"abc123","1":"abc123","2":"abc","3":"abc","4":"efgh"},"comp_id":{"0":1395,"1":2467,"2":4567,"3":1596,"4":111222},"retailer":{"0":"Shmo","1":"Joe","2":"Jon","3":"Sam","4":"Tim"},"price":{"0":7.49,"1":5.17,"2":89.99,"3":13.99,"4":4.98}}
stock = {"uid":{"0":"abc123","1":"abc123","2":"abc","3":"abc","4":"efgh"},"comp_id":{"0":1395,"1":2467,"2":4567,"3":1596,"4":111222},"availability":{"0":"True","1":"True","2":"True","3":"True","4":"True"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s = pd.DataFrame(stock)
s = s.set_index(['comp_id','uid'])
```

The Code:

```
df.insert(2, 'availability', df.set_index(['uid','comp_id']).index.map(s['availability']))
```

The Error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Another look:

```
for idx in df.set_index(['uid','comp_id']).index:
       map(idx, s['availability'])
```

The Goal:

Often, I'm having to inject one series from one df into another df and don't want to have to use merge and then reorder col names with a list comprehension. I would rather manipulate the dataframes underlying dictionary structure using ordereddict or use inject + map. If you could combine these when the dataframes are first created, that would be cool too.

Comment: Map doesn't work like this. You need to pass a dict or a callable.

Comment: Could you provide reproducible sample data sets?

Comment: @MaxU very similar to my other question, the code worked for single index but not multi-index. i guess map doesn't like taking a tuple to map to a multi-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [174]: vals = df[['uid','comp_id']].set_index(['comp_id','uid']).join(s).values

In [175]: vals
Out[175]:
array([['True'],
       ['True'],
       ['True'],
       ['True'],
       ['True']], dtype=object)

In [176]: df.insert(2, 'availability', vals)

In [177]: df
Out[177]:
   comp_id  price availability retailer     uid
0     1395   7.49         True     Shmo  abc123
1     2467   5.17         True      Joe  abc123
2     4567  89.99         True      Jon     abc
3     1596  13.99         True      Sam     abc
4   111222   4.98         True      Tim    efgh
```

Comment: any idea why df[['uid','comp_id']].join(s, on=['uid','comp_id']) does not work while your code above does work? i read that with join it defaults to joining on index unless you specify which columns with the on which must relate to the index of the passed dataframe

Comment: also this is really no different than merge, but by using values, it allows me to bypass using the df[cols] syntax which is what i ultimately wanted.

Comment: seems like update works from indexes so figured it could be possible